# Node.JS HTTP Response Returns Nothing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to iterate through a MongoDB cursor object and return all records from a collection and then using the respond method in Node outout to the browser.

The problem I have is no response seems to be fired.

I have tried putting response.end() inside the loop but it then doesn't iterate through the results.

I have tried response.end() in different places also. Here is the code

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log("Nodelistr is connected to MongoDB\n");
                response.writeHead(200);

                db.collection('todo', function(err, collection){            
                    collection.find(function(err, cursor) {
                        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                            for(docs in doc){
                                if(docs == "_id"){
                                }else{
                                    var test = docs + " : " + doc[docs];
                                }
                            }
                            data = data.toString("utf8").replace("{{TEST}}", test);
                            response.write(data);

                            //console.dir(doc);
                        })           
                        response.end();         
                    });
                });

            };

        });
```

Comment: `data` is not initialized in the code snippet you posted

Comment: console.log(data); to see what is in data

Comment: When console.log(data) is placed outside the cursor.each I get a buffer returned to the console (<Buffer 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 09 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 09 09 3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 4e 6f 64 65 6c 69 73 74 72 21 3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 0a 09 09 3c 6c 69 6e 6b 20 ...>) Although when its placed inside the cursor.each the .html file is returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what you're trying to do with the uninitialized `data` variable and the documents as you iterate over them, but the general problem is that you need to wait to call `response.end();` until you've hit the end of the cursor.  That's indicated by `doc` being null in the `cursor.each` callback.

The middle part of your code should follow this general approach:

```
db.collection('todo', function(err, collection){            
    collection.find(function(err, cursor) {
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            if (doc) {
                ...  // initialize data from doc
                response.write(data);
            } else {
                // doc is null, so the cursor is exhausted
                response.end();         
            }
        })           
    });
});
```